# Flutter ios app icon unchanged while switching apps

Tags: ios, flutter, icons

so I'm releaseing my Flutter app, after changing the app icon the app icon shows as expected in the main screen and in notification center, but when switching apps, the app icon still shows the Flutter logo, any idea how to correct this? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: https://appicon.co generate your app icon from here and replace with your Assets.xcassets folder may be you don't icon in this dimensions. and device is using default icon. then uninstall your application and reinstall.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Restart your iphone once and run the app again this should solve, for me i also faced the same the above trick worked for me.